# Can an object be deconstructed on an atomic Level?

Tags: atomic-physics, atoms

Can a machine deconstruct objects on an atomic level. But is that possible? Not the machine per say but the simple (not that simple) act of what it does. Ex.Taking a broken computer and separating the different atoms so it would be just a group of atoms instead of a computer.

If you have any suggested readings on the topic that would be greatly appreciated.

Q: Can an object be broken up to be just separate atoms?

Comment: Yes. Put some salt grains into the water. Ions are bound by electrostatic interaction. When immersed in water, due to permittivity, force decreases and ions separate.

Comment: We currently have machines that can construct things atom-by-atom. They do this by picking up one atom from somewhere and putting it where they want it. Being able to do this necessitates that given enough time the same machines should be able to completely deconstruct an item atom-by-atom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change an object, for example a metal, to the vapor phase, then the atoms will generally be separate.  In other words, the atoms will no longer be bonded. It is broken up into just separate atoms.

If you had a mixture of metals to start with, then in principle you could separate them through a distillation process.

There are many chemical and physical separation processes that would allow you to separate a computer or other object into is elements.

Think of gold mines.  They take gold ore which has as little as 1 gram per ton (1 part per million), yet they purify gold to >99.9% purity.